# Storing the IV with the ciphertext Crypto++ CBC AES encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++, initialization-vector

I'm trying to encrypt(and decrypt after) a file using AES in CBC mode and Crypto++ library

Here's what I already did:

```
using namespace CryptoPP;
AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;

//generating the key and iv
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
```

To encrypt a file,I open it in binary mode,and dump the content to a string :

```
std::ifstream fin(file_path, std::ios::binary);
if (!fin)
{
    std::cout << "error";
}
std::ostringstream ostrm;
ostrm << fin.rdbuf();
std::string plaintext(ostrm.str());
fin.close();
```

Then,I encrypt this string using the key and iv previously generated:

```
std::string ciphertext;

AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.length() + 1);
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
```

Now,i want to write the encrypted string to a file,and store the IV with it,since the iv doesn't need to be kept secret,ideally at the beginning or the end of the ciphertext

Here comes the problem : the IV is a byte array and the ciphertext is a string,do i need to convert one of the two to another type,or can i just do :

```
std::ofstream fdout(file_path2, std::ios::binary);
if (!fdout)
{
    std::cout << "error";
}
fdout << iv;
fdout << ciphertext;
fdout.close();
```

When i will try to decrypt this file,how can i extract the iv and ciphertext separately ? The IV is 16 Bytes long,but here i'm completely lost and i don't know how to do.

Comment: Is there no pre-made primitive doing that for you in this lib? No? Then be careful and read up base64-encoding.

Comment: I didn't see anything to do that in the wiki.I can base64 encode the iv (which is a byte[]) to a string,but decode process is more complicated,since it converts the encoded string to a decoded string,and i want to recover my byte array :)

Answer (score 2):

> Storing the IV with the ciphertext Crypto++ CBC AES encryption

Some of the code you are using is a bit unusual to me. I'll pick a couple things out and show you some of the Crypto++ ways.

Before you begin, take a look at [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) and [Pumping Data](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data) on the Crypto++ wiki. Remember that data flows from sources to sinks. In between the data encounters filters which transform the data.

---

```
std::ifstream fin(file_path, std::ios::binary);
if (!fin)
{
    std::cout << "error";
}
std::ostringstream ostrm;
ostrm << fin.rdbuf();
std::string plaintext(ostrm.str());
fin.close();
```

A Crypto++ `FileSource` has a constructor that takes a `std::istream`. You could do something like the following. Also see [`FileSource`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FileSource) on the Crypto++ wiki.

```
std::ifstream fin(file_path, std::ios::binary);
FileSource source(fin, true /*pump all*/, NULLPTR);
...
```

---

> ```
> AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
> CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);
> ```

`ExternalCipher` are for the FIPS DLL. You can use them without the DLL, but they exist for the DLL. Usually you use:

```
 CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
```

Also, you usually want to avoid a *confidentiality-only* mode. Typically you want to use an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode of operation. It provides *confidentiality and authenticity*.

Crypto++ provides CCM, EAX and GCM authenticated encryption modes of operation. OCB and EAX are very good choices. EAX mode is documented at [EAX Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/EAX_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki. OCB is not available at the moment. We are getting ready to check-in OCB mode.

---

> Now,i want to write the encrypted string to a file,and store the IV with it,since the iv doesn't need to be kept secret,ideally at the beginning or the end of the ciphertext

Use something like the following. I did not compile it, so you will need to fix the typos.

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAXIMUM_KEYLENGTH), iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);

RandomNumberSource rs1(prng, AES::MAXIMUM_KEYLENGTH, new ArraySink(key, key.size()));
RandomNumberSource rs2(prng, AES::BLOCKSIZE, new ArraySink(iv, iv.size()));

HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

std::cout << "Key: ";
encoder.Put(key, key.size());
encoder.MessageEnd();
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "IV: ";
encoder.Put(iv, iv.size());
encoder.MessageEnd();
std::cout << std::endl;

EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

// Plaintext message
std::string message;

// Output file
FileSink file("message.enc");

// Source wrappers
ArraySource as(iv, iv.size(), true,
    new Redirector(file));

// Source wrapper
StringSource ss(message, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor,
       new Redirector(file)));
```

---

> When i will try to decrypt this file,how can i extract the iv and ciphertext separately ?

Use something like the following.

```
// Key is from previous example. It cannot change
SecByteBlock key(AES::MAXIMUM_KEYLENGTH), iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);    
FileSource fs("message.enc", false /* DO NOT Pump All */);

// Attach new filter
ArraySink as(iv, iv.size());
fs.Attach(new Redirector(as));
fs.Pump(AES::BLOCKSIZE);  // Pump first 16 bytes

EAX<AES>::Decryption decryptor;
decryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());

// Detach previously attached filter, attach new filter
ByteQueue queue;
fs.Detach(new StreamTransformationFilter(decryptor, new Redirector(queue)));
fs.PumpAll();  // Pump remainder of bytes
```

The encrypted data will be in a `ByteQueue`. It does *not* provide C++ iterator-like functionality, like a pointer and a size. To get the data out of the `ByteQueue` you transfer it or copy it to another filter or a sink:

```
SecByteBlock block(queue.MaxRetrievable());
ArraySink sink(block, block.size());
queue.TransferTo(sink);
```

You can get the data out of the `ByteQueue` and put it in a`std::string` with:

```
std::string recovered;
StringSink sink(recovered);
queue.TransferTo(sink);
```

And you can print the IV recovered from the file with:

```
HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));

std::cout << "IV: ";
encoder.Put(iv, iv.size());
encoder.MessageEnd();
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you ! There is something i don't understand : with this
FileSource source(fin, true /*pump all*/, NULLPTR); ,where do you store the file content ? I also get an " fin :multiples initialisations with your ifstream/filesource example

Comment: @Einder - Ask a new question and show your code. I need to see what you are doing. Also show the full error message.

Comment: I got the error fixed (fin was the name i was using previously to read the plaintext),but my question remains

Comment: As requested,i asked a new question with the code i'm using.

Comment: :Another problem here: when using StringSource from your example,the executable crashes.according to visual studio the syntax is correct,but it keeps crashing at this point.the same error occurs if i replace the redirector by a StringSink.

Comment: Sir, I think you should update the answer to the latest version of the framework. As you know `EAX` mode does not support encryption/decryption via `StreamTransformationFilter`. For the process of encryption, `AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter` and for the decryption, `AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter` must be used.

Answer (score 0):

The `StringSink` has the following documentation:

> A `StringSink` serves as a destination for string data in the pipelining paradigm. **The data can be binary or ASCII.**

So although it is a string, it is internally an *octet- or byte string*. So yes, you can just save the IV and ciphertext that way.

But to be sure, just compare the length of the result with the IV size (16 bytes) and ciphertext size together. If it is equal then you should be fine.