# Loading large image file throws exception std::bad_alloc in CryptoPP::FileSource

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

In a c++ project I am using CryptoPP for performing AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption on image files. Below is the code I am using (from [Storing the IV with the ciphertext Crypto++ CBC AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461770))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <osrng.h>
#include <files.h>
#include <modes.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    string _key = "0123456789abcdef";
    SecByteBlock key((const byte*)_key.data(), _key.size());

    RandomNumberSource rs2(prng, AES::BLOCKSIZE, new ArraySink(iv, iv.size()));

    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
    encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv, iv.size());


    // Plaintext message
    ByteQueue queue;
    FileSource source("E:\\ori_pics\\20161224_143119.jpg", true, new Redirector(queue));

    SecByteBlock block(queue.MaxRetrievable());
    ArraySink sink(block, block.size());
    queue.TransferTo(sink);

    // Output file
    FileSink file("D:\\enc_pics\\20161224_143119.jpg");

    // Source wrappers
    ArraySource as(iv, iv.size(), true, new Redirector(file));
    ArraySource ss(block, block.size(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(encryptor, new Redirector(file), BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING));

}
```

In this program, I am using random IV and fixed key. I am writing IV at the beginning of the out put file and then encrypted file content with `PKCS_PADDING`.

Above program works very well when I use .txt file as input, it is generating encrypted txt file. But when I provide .jpg file of size 55,35,433 bytes (5MB approx.) then exception `std::bad_alloc` is thrown by line of code:
`FileSource source("E:\\ori_pics\\20161224_143119.jpg", true, new Redirector(queue));` from file `misc.h` from function `CallNewHandler()`.

What I am doing wrong? Why, .txt file encryption is successful by the same program but .jpg fails?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. I filed a report here: https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/962

Comment: The issue has been fixed upstream.